# Laravel URL to Adding style?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code in email.blade.php

```
 {{ URL::to('password/reset' , array($token)) }}
```

Which generates

```
  <a href="password/reset/hfhfjhghsasdgsd">password/reset/hfhfjhghsasdgsd</a>
```

How could I make it look like this:

```
  <a href="password/reset/hfhfjhghsasdgsd" style="color:blue">Reset Password</a>
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: inline styling can give you nightmare. stylesheets are created for a purpoe.

Comment: well this is for email template :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use link_to helper:

```
{{ link_to('password/reset/hfhfjhghsasdgsd', 'Reset Password', array('style' => 'color:blue')) }}
```

Or

```
{{ HTML::link('password/reset/hfhfjhghsasdgsd', 'Reset Password', array('style' => 'color:blue')) }}
```